# "Couldn't lock /home/marc/sent?" in Mutt

Tags: linux, locking, mutt

For some reason Mutt can't get a lock on /home/marc/sent in order to send messages. When I try to send a message, I get this error message:

```
Couldn't lock /home/marc/sent?
```

and I can't send it.

I looked at the file permissions, and I have `rw` on the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
# vi /etc/Muttrc
set record="/var/mail/sent"
set mbox="/var/mail/mbox"
set mbox_type=mbox

# chmod 777 /var/mail/sent
```

Comment: You better explain a bit your solution, if you want to write a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

mutt have acquired a lock on sent
Remove lock file which is present under `/home/$USER/sent*`

```
rm /home/$USER/sent.lock 
          OR
rm /home/$USER/sent*
```

If needed you can use sudo with above

In your case it will be

```
/home/marc/sent*
```